# AngularJS - How to validate URL dynamic params

Tags: angularjs, routes, url-parameters, dynamic-url

Part of the route is like this

```
.when('/id/:id',
  {
    templateUrl: 'id.html',
    controller: myController,
   })
```

I want to validate if ':id' is from a set of ids, which is from a service functional call. If not, the page rendering should be prevented.

I got this part working by adding resolve in the route. The code is like this

```
.when('/id/:id',
        {
          templateUrl: 'id.html',
          controller: myController,
          resolve: {
            validate: function($q, $route, myService) {
              myService.getProjects().then(function(data) {
                var defer = $q.defer(),
                    project = $route.current.params.project;
                if (myContains(data.projects, project)) {
                  defer.resolve();
                } else {
                  defer.reject({authenticated: false});
                }
                return defer.promise;
              });
            }
          }
        })
```

However when the promise is rejected, it does not fire up $routeChangeError, which I wrote like this

```
myApp.app.module.config(['$routeProvider', myApp.app.config])
.run(
  ['$rootScope', '$location', function($rootScope, $location) {
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeError',
        function(event, current, previous, rejection) {
      var rejection = {};
          if (!rejection.authenticated) {
            $location.path('/').replace();
          }
        });
  }]);
```

====update===
I got it working. The mistake I made earlier was to have 'return defer.promise' inside of then block.

Comment: Check it in your controller and redirect to another route on error

Comment: This for like an admin back-end? If so just use a bool with true for admin and false for not. It would be better than looping through a list. Just a suggestion if thats the case.

Comment: @Phill, I tried that, but the url still show the wrong id param for like half second before redirecting to homepage.Thanks

Comment: @Joe, it is for the frontend. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have the list of ids ,the this is how you can do,

```
.when('/id/:id', {
            templateUrl: 'id.html',
            controller: myController,
            resolve: {

                validateid: ["$q", "$routeParams", function($q, $routeParams) {

                    var id = Enumerable.From(arrayofids)
                        .Where(function(x) {
                            return x.id == $routeParams.id
                        });

                    if (id) {
                        return $q.when($routeParams.id);
                    } else {
                        return $q.reject({
                            authenticated: false
                        });
                    }

                }],

            }
        }
```

resolve is a place where you can do all sort of action before navigation take place,

i had used linq.js which make all sort of iteration quite easily,i recommend you to just use it for once,you will love it

Comment: Thanks maddygoround! I got this part working, however, after adding $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeError', function(){}), I found $routeChangeError is never called when the promise is rejected. I'll add this part in the question. thanks!